# Python mysql commands don't show

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote the code to run SQL commands in a mysql console while the input is not 'exit', but the commands do not show when the SQL is entered. Please help me solve this problem.

```
import mysql.connector
import sys


def repeat():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='ace',
        passwd='1234'
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    x = input('Enter SQL > ')
    if x != 'exit':
        mycursor.execute(x)
        return repeat()
    else:
        print('Work with the database is complete')
        mydb.close()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    repeat()
```

Comment: When you say the commands don't show, do you mean they are not executed in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Is autocommit turned off? If so, you have to commit your transaction to see results.

Also, your recursive structure looks awkward and unnecessary. Consider a `while` loop with an exit flag to break the loop when exit is signaled.

```
def repeat():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='ace',
        passwd='1234'
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    exit = False
    while not exit:
        x = input('Enter SQL > ')
        if x != 'exit':
            mycursor.execute(x)
            mydb.commit()
        else:
            print('Work with the database is complete')
            exit = True

    mydb.close()
    sys.exit()
```

It's possible that your commands are not being run because you're winding up a recursion stack, which is creating new DB connections each time, so you only explicitly close the last one, leaving the rest dangling upon exit. I'm not sure what mysql's behavior here would be but the above code is definitely a much better practice. See if that resolves your problem.

Comment: still doesnt work. its says 'Unread result found'
I need to run any mysql commands with this, only if not entered exit. mydb.commit() dont help. Its just dont print anything.

Comment: Try `mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)`

Comment: still same, Friend.